# WhenEvent does not detect event

Tags: differential-equations, debugging, event-detection

I'm having some trouble stopping `NDSolve` when the solutions gets outside of a given domain. There are five unknowns, and `NDSolve` should stop when the solution becomes not *canonical*, where *canonical* is defined by the following function:

```
canonical[list_List] := Last@Sort@ Flatten[NestList[Reverse /@ # &, 
                                 NestList[RotateLeft, list, Length[list] - 1], 1], 1]
```

Understanding `canonical` is not required for the question, but let me explain in few words: the problem whose solution are given by `NDSolve` is invariant by circular permutations and symmetry; so `{2,3,4,5,1}` does not bring any additional information if I already have `{5,4,3,2,1}`. That's why I want to stop `NDSolve` when it gets out of my "canonical domain".

The following function checks if a list is canonical or not:

```
nonCanonicalQ[vals_] := (vals != canonical[vals])
```

For example:

```
nonCanonicalQ[{5,4,3,2,1}] (* False: means that it's a canonical list *)
nonCanonicalQ[{3,4,5,1,2}] (* True: means it's not a canonical list *)
```

Now, let's use it in `WhenEvent` using `NDSolve`, with a very basic example (all solutions are constant, except the last one which is linear):

```
vars = Array[s, 5];
varsOt = Through[vars[t]];

sysDAE0 = {{s[1]'[t], s[2]'[t], s[3]'[t], s[4]'[t], s[5]'[t]} == {0,  0, 0, 0, 1}, 
           {s[1][0], s[2][0], s[3][0], s[4][0], s[5][0]} == {4, 3, 2, 1, 0}}

{solDAE} = NDSolve[{sysDAE0}~Join~{WhenEvent[Evaluate@nonCanonicalQ[varsOt], 
  "StopIntegration"]}, vars, {t, -1000, 1000}];
solDAE = vars /. solDAE
```

This outputs a solution valid on domain $[-1000,1000]$. However, it should have triggered the `WhenEvent` because

```
nonCanonicalQ[Through[solDAE[0]]] (* False *)
nonCanonicalQ[Through[solDAE[100]]] (* True *)
```

The integration should have stopped somewhere between $t=0$ and $t=100$.

Comment: Did you define vars and varsOt?

Comment: @Cassini Thank you, I forgot to include their definition in the OP. Edited.

Comment: It seems to have something to do with the evaluation of the predicate because WhenEvent[{s[1][t], s[2][t], s[3][t], s[4][t], s[5][t]} != 
  canonical[{s[1][t], s[2][t], s[3][t], s[4][t], 
    s[5][t]}], "StopIntegration"] stops at t=3.

Comment: The third component in each side of `nonCanonicalQ[varsOt]` is the same, `s[3][t]`, and the relation between them `NotEqual` should always come up `False`. This doesn't happen with the solution because `nonCanonicalQ` is evaluated on the solution values, not on the symbolic expressions as in the `NDSolve` code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cassinis solution is one possibility to solve your problem and he is right in assuming that it has to do with evaluation order. The following is a summary of techniques which I found helpful when investigating situations when `NDSolve` doesn't behave as one would expect.

`WhenEvent` does have the attribute `HoldAll` and I guess that is the reason why you did put the `Evaluate` within it. The `Evaluate` seems to work but does evaluate with symbolic arguments before `NDSolve` starts to solve. It will evaluate to:

```
 {s[1][t],s[2][t],s[3][t],s[4][t],s[5][t]} != {s[5][t],s[4][t],s[3][t],s[2][t],s[1][t]}
```

which then will be used in every step with numerical values for the `s[n][t]` in the event check while `NDSolve` is running and of course will always evaluate to false and thus never trigger the event (strictly speaking it could even evaluate to true for cases where it shouldn't, but that doesn't happen for your example). Here is a simple change to `nonCanonicalQ` which shows what happens:

```
nonCanonicalQ[vals_] := Module[{result},
  result = vals != canonical[vals];
  Print["nonCanonicalQ"[vals] -> result];
  result
]
```

rerunning the call to `NDSolve` after making that change will show that `nonCanonicalQ` will be evaluated only once and give the mentioned result.

Cassinis answer shows how to solve the problem by explicitly writing out the variables and avoid the `Evaluate`. Using the above definition for `nonCanonicalQ` will show that `nonCanonicalQ` then is also evaluated only once at the beginning and return:

```
{s[1][t],s[2][t],s[3][t],s[4][t],s[5][t]} !=
  canonical[{s[1][t],s[2][t],s[3] [t],s[4][t],s[5][t]}]
```

the `canonical` in that expression will only be evaluated at every time step with numeric arguments and make `WhenEvent` trigger as intended (you could check that with a similar change to `canonical` as I have shown for `nonCanonicalQ`).

Of course there are several other possibilities to achieve the same thing and without writing out the variables to make that work. One very simple solution would be to change either `canonical` or `nonCanonicalQ` so that they only evaluate for numeric arguments, e.g.:

```
ClearAll@canonical;
canonical[list : {__?NumericQ}] := (
  Last@Sort@Flatten[NestList[
   Reverse /@ # &, NestList[RotateLeft, list, Length[list] - 1], 1], 1]
)
```

Using that with the OP's rest of the code should work as intended, which can be checked by using my printing version of `nonCanonicalQ`.

Note that it is important to `ClearAll` before making the new definition, otherwise the old one will still evaluate early. If you want to go back to the original definition to try the following solution you should also use a `ClearAll` to really verify that it really does work.

Instead of evaluating early and avoiding evaluation with symbolic arguments you can insert the variables into the `WhenEvent` with something like this:

```
With[{vars = varsOt},
  solDAE = NDSolveValue[
    {sysDAE0}~Join~{WhenEvent[nonCanonicalQ[vars], "StopIntegration"]}, 
    vars, {t, -1000, 1000}
  ]
]
```

which will work even without the `Evaluate` and without the restriction of `canonical` to numeric arguments. I would also suggest to adopt `NDSolveValue` which is avoiding some extra steps to extract the result.

Answer (score 5):

This works:

```
  {solDAE} = 
    NDSolve[
      {sysDAE0} 
       ~ Join ~ 
      {WhenEvent[
         nonCanonicalQ[
           {s[1][t], s[2][t], s[3][t], s[4][t], s[5][t]}], 
           "StopIntegration"]}, 
      vars, {t, -1000, 1000}]
```

Comment: Indeed... Any idea why the other solution does not?

Comment: I have a vague idea that it has to do with Hold..., but I'm sure one of the MMA wizards here can tell you.